# Can you add the visual editor to the description field for custom taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, tinymce, visual-editor

Can you add the visual editor to the description field for custom taxonomies? It would be nice to have this option available when you edit an entry for a taxonomy be it core or custom.

Comment: The following solution from @Butuzov works perfectly [Replace Taxomony Description Field with Visual/WYSIWYG Editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190510/replace-taxomony-description-field-with-visual-wysiwyg-editor/190854#190854)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just wrote the function. It'll display the tinymce editor in every custom taxonomy description right now. Surely you can edit to show it for only some specific taxonomy.

```
/**
 * Display advanced TinyMCE editor in taxonomy page
 */
function wpse_7156_enqueue_category() {
    global $pagenow, $current_screen;

    if( $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' ) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/template.php');

        wp_tiny_mce( false, array( 'editor_selector' => 'description', 'elements' => 'description', 'mode' => 'exact' ));
    } 
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_7156_enqueue_category' );
```

You can provide the first argument in `wp_tiny_mce` as `true` if you want a stripped version of tinyMCE

Comment: You nailed it Tareq, thanks! I'm pretty sure they're moving this in to a real API for 3.3, but for now this is a simple solution. I'll award the bounty tomorrow when WPSE lets me. :)

Comment: +1 for simplicity. Adding to my snippets and will try soon. Thanks

Comment: @Maugly, agreed. I tried it and you may want to modify it to work with the action=edit, because on the quick edit screen #description is used in the taxonomy table. #tag-description is used for the description text box on the quick edit screen, but your space is limited, because of the two column setup.

Comment: just a reminder to @hsatterwhite to award bounty

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, done and done. Have a good one!

Comment: This breaks the edit page for any term in wordpress 3.3+. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-33-breaks-wp_tiny_mce

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_tiny_mce() in`

Comment: Its a bit outdated. This helped me: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190510/replace-taxomony-description-field-with-visual-wysiwyg-editor

Answer (score 2):

**Have you tried The** [Rich Text Tags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rich-text-tags/) **Plugin?**

- It does exactly what you need.
- Works with custom taxonomies.
- Works well with images.
- Includes the new WP internal linking.
- It is regularly updated.

Screenshot:

[image: Rich Text Tags Screenshot]

Comment: I have not heard about this. I appreciate the answer and link with screenshot. In addition to the accepted answer, this is also a great solution. Thank you Maugly!

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, no.

You could, however, write a custom javascript which applies the appropriate classes to the entry field for the custom taxonomy description.

If what you really want to do, however, is create a "many-to-many" relationship between posts (e.g. a post type of "Tires" and a post type of "Cars"), then WordPress doesn't (currently) have a facility for this. However, the [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin *does* provide this functionality (and gives you a lot more flexibility to create complex relationships).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not trying to relate posts to other posts. I'm just trying to add the visual editor to the description field for taxonomies.