# How to modify default taxonomy field to a single text field?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Am trying to find solutions but I can't find one. I want to modify the WordPress field in admin specifically the description I want to update it into a single text field.

[image]

Comment: It is the default by WP or the custom field?

Comment: @Quang default of WP

Comment: I don't see this field in wp-admin? Please let me know?

Comment: On the edit taxonomy page? Can refer to this link https://postimg.cc/fSNttksj

Comment: I feel this is the custom field and it is developed with the theme. If you can read the code theme, you can edit this or you can find this in the Custom Fields(The ACF plugin). Maybe it is set in this page.

Comment: Input field should have acf prefix or something right? so perhaps upon creation of taxonomy. I'll take a look and get back to you.

Comment: Yes. It has acf prefix because it created from this plugin.

Comment: Yep, in my case it doesn't have one so i'll take a look and will let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85575/discussion-between-leonardeveloper-and-quang).